# Tessel 2 virtual machine creation error

Tags: virtualbox, tessel

I am creating tessel 2 virtual machine on ubuntu 14.04 by using following command and getting errors

```
t2-vm create
```

I am getting following error message

```
Downloading image...
downloaded ...
Creating VM...
VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/haider/.tessel/vm.vdi' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 178 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
VBoxManage: error: Invalid UUID or filename "/home/haider/.tessel/vm.vdi"
Unhandled rejection Error: 1
    at Object.ensureErrorObject (/home/haider/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/t2-vm/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:261:20)
    at Promise._rejectCallback (/home/haider/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/t2-vm/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:472:22)
    at /home/haider/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/t2-vm/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:489:17
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/haider/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/t2-vm/etc.js:47:14)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
```

I have installed all Prerequisites which includes nodejs, tessel-cli, tessel usb rules, virtual box and its extension pack. The versions are as follows

```
$ nodejs -v
v4.8.4
$ vboxmanage -v
5.0.40r115130
```

Answer (score 0):

The line indicate that the version is not supported :

```
VBoxManage: error: Could not get the storage format of the medium '/home/haider/.tessel/vm.vdi' (VERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

In fact your VBox version is 5.0.40r115130 and the actual version is 5.1.26, try to update your version before install Tessel.

You can also try to check the MD5 signature of your file if you have it.

Comment: I updated the VBox to 5.1.26 but still the same error occurs. I should check MD5 signature of which file?

Comment: You should check the MD5 of vm.vdi file with :
`md5sum /home/haider/.tessel/vm.vdi`.

But you need to know the hash reference and i don't know if you have it.